# Trying to create shortcode listing custom posts, but formating not being included

Tags: posts, wp-query, shortcode

I am trying to create my own shortcode I can use to list WooCommerce products. The titles and content display fine, however the html formatting I am trying to use (such as `<strong>` and `<p>`) gets displayed after the title and content instead of with it.

`function gr_woo_product_function() {
    $grcontent;
$args = array(

        'post_type' => 'product',

        'posts_per_page' => 30,
        'orderby' => 'ASC'
    );

        $my_query = new WP_Query($args); 
 while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
 $grcontent.="<p><strong>".the_title()."</strong><br/>".the_content()."</p>";
endwhile;
return $grcontent;
}
add_shortcode('wooproduct', 'gr_woo_product_function');`

Every title should be in bold and every product should have it's own paragraph. But instead each product is listed first and after that there are a bunch of empty paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_title()` and `the_content()` both include an echo. 
You want to build a string, so use [get_the_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) and [get_the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) instead.